# How to center an item inside of a DIV

Tags: html, css

please see my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nobosh/kABaJ/

My question is, inside the the #Frame I have an image inside of #previewItem, How can I get #previewItem and the image inside to be centered horizontally and vertically in side the #frame no matter what #frame's dimensions are? Using CSS, w/o JS.

Thanks

Comment: in your code you have 2 times the id `frame` ,something which is not valid, and also I don't see somewhere in your code the `previewItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#frame{
    display:table;
}


#previewItem{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; //centers vertically
    margin: 0px auto; //centers horizontally
}
```

Comment: That seems a lot simpler than previous suggestions , so thanks for that. Problem here is that I'm position #frame with  position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 top: 36px; which seems to be breaking the suggestion ,right ?

Comment: Try it out.  I think that you should be able to position the frame wherever you'd like.  The position: and display: properties should be independent of one another.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look here as it seems to answer your question pretty well.

Not the most elegant solution, but it does work:

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

EDIT: the horizontal centering can be accomplished either by setting the parent div's width to 100% with a "text-align: center" defined, or via auto margins.

Comment: Thanks wookie, horizontal is easy. Vertical not so much :)

Answer (score 1):

In that example, the inner div also had the id of frame. Updating that to previewItem and adding `text-align:center;` under #previewItem should the horizontal alignment.

The vertical alignment is harder to set and hard in IE6 (and 7?). However if you know the size of the inner div (previewItem), then you can set align the inner div easily using this snippet:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: x em;
height:y em;
margin-top: -x/2 em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
margin-left: -y/2 em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
```

And just sub in the appropriate values of x and y

Comment: Thanks but that's just horizontal, what about vertical?

Comment: Thanks but I don't know the size, that would require JS